# Python: Getting value deep in a details string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ive been trying to reference the value of BUCKET_NAME below but python doesnt like my way of doing it

wr_bucket_name = wr_details.resources.metadata.BUCKET doesnt catch it

```
{
  "compartment_id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaat4orwuuyjigoejqngwblbv6a577ueqpavc27rslbdyyc4dckiwia",
  "id": "1405161f-1eca-4b3c-a0e1-10ceb17c6cae",
  "operation_type": "COPY_OBJECT",
  "percent_complete": 100.0,
  "resources": [
    {
      "action_type": "READ",
      "entity_type": "object",
      "entity_uri": "/n/oraclepca/b/qe_ta_sourceBucket_eSfBHb_WorkRequestUtilitiesTest/o/file.zip",
      "identifier": null,
      "metadata": {
        "BUCKET": "qe_ta_sourceBucket_eSfBHb_WorkRequestUtilitiesTest",
        "NAMESPACE": "oraclepca",
        "OBJECT": "file.zip",
        "REGION": "us-phoenix-1"
      }
    },
    {
      "action_type": "WRITTEN",
      "entity_type": "object",
      "entity_uri": "/n/oraclepca/b/qe_ta_destinationBucket_eSfBHb_WorkRequestUtilitiesTest/o/config.py",
      "identifier": null,
      "metadata": {
        "BUCKET": "qe_ta_destinationBucket_eSfBHb_WorkRequestUtilitiesTest",
        "NAMESPACE": "oraclepca",
        "OBJECT": "config.py",
        "REGION": "us-phoenix-1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "time_accepted": "2020-08-10T15:49:37+00:00",
  "time_finished": "2020-08-10T15:49:38+00:00",
  "time_started": "2020-08-10T15:49:38+00:00"
}
```

Comment: It is `wr_details["resources"][0]["metadata"]["BUCKET"]`

Comment: As a hint - consider this: ```wr_bucket_name = wr_details["resources"][0]["metadata"]["BUCKET"]``` but totally try reading about `list` and `dict` in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is

```
wr_details["resources"][0]["metadata"]["BUCKET"]
```

Or within a loop as `resources` is a list:

```
for resource in wr_details["resources"]:
    bucket = resource["metadata"]["BUCKET"]
```